# parse excel file.tmp using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I made a html form to import excel sheet into mysql. After loading from form, the file gets stored in memory with .tmp extension. How can I parse this .tmp file using phpexcel? or is there a better way to load it from html form and parse directly?
My code;

```
<form action='load.php' method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <p><input type="file" name='excelfile'/></p>
   <p><button type="button">upload</button></p>     
</form>



//load.php 
<?php

if (!empty($_FILES["excelfile"])) {      

      if ($excel["error"] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
          echo "<p>An error occurred.</p>";
          exit;
        }
      else {
          echo "File uploaded"; 

          require '../class/PHPExcel.php';
          require_once '../class/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php'; 

          $path = ????;   //....how to parse this file, now stored as filename.tmp
          $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);

          //........
        }

  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get tmp path as following:

```
$path=$_FILES['excelfile']['tmp_name'];
```

Comment: thanks @jd namera , but why do I keep getting this error "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www.."